# "wouldn't hope so." vs "would hope not."

Tags: responses

[You're disencouraged to say "I do**n't** hope so" instead of "I hope **not**"](https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/hope), but what about "[I wouldn't/shouldn't hope so](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/es/diccionario/ingles-espanol/i-hope-so)" ?

Comment: Saying that you 'don't hope'  or 'wouldn't hope' that something happens could imply that you are indifferent to the outcome. Saying that you hope it _doesn't_ happen is a much stronger statement.

Comment: Yes, you can use "I wouldn't hope so," but that has a different emphasis. It is more formal and it can make you sound stuffy or elitist -- at least in AmE. Why do you find "I hope not" to be not enough?